# install android sdk on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-sdk-tools

I have downloaded the android sdk tools now according to [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-developing-android.html) I should update it so I go to it's directory and type:

```
./android
```

when sdk manager opens I can see that sdk tools is installed but there isn't anything else to do. But since Qt doesn't recognize sdk so I assume I have not completely installed it yet. Is there anything else I should do to complete the installation?

Edit:
I tried somthing else. I downloaded ADT bundle. in that folder there is a sdk folder I used that folder and it worked with qt. But in that directory there are some folders that in my original sdk didn't exist:

```
extras
platform-tools
system-images
```

Comment: what is the problem that your are facing

Comment: I want to use qt android. but qt doesn't recognize sdk. So I think I'm not installing it correctly.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-on-ubuntu

Comment: Follow This link [enter link description here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu)

Comment: [Click Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) Follow This Link For install android sdk on ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go with ADT Bundle for Linux, you can get it from following link

[Android ADT for Linux](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

- Extract the downloaded package.
- Download OpenJDK for Linux and install
- Update QT if necessary
- Add your location of SDK to QT
- Now you might be able to run Eclipse from your ADT location

ADT bundle contains 
Eclipse + ADT plugin - A Customized eclipse with location of Android SDK is presetted 
Android SDK Tools - Inside tools folder, contains android SDK services like Emulator, Hierarchy viewer, SQLite etc
Android Platform-tools - Contains the Compiler runtime, ADB etc
The latest Android platform - Contains each and every android versions you have downloaded with platform specific samples and themes for emulator
The latest Android system image for the emulator - Contains a system image for each of the emulator for the platforms you downloaded

Comment: eventually that was what I did tnx

Answer (score 0):

Download Android SDK for Linux from [Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Extract the folder.

Now navigate to eclipse folder and run eclipse from there. android sdk is already integrated in this eclipse package and you will also get the latest SDK with this package.

**UPDATE: Directory path for QT**

**Android SDK Location:** /home/vipul/dev/android-sdk-linux

**Android SDK Location:** /home/vipul/dev/android-ndk-r8e

**JDK Location:** /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386

Comment: I have done that. But then which directory should I pass to Qt so it can find sdk?

Comment: tnx, but doesn't work yet, please check my edits in the question.